# Flashpunk Draw.circle dissapearing

Tags: flash, user-interface, draw

I don't quite understand how to use the draw class from flashpunk. Everything works fine except the circle I draw disappears.

```
package assets {

import net.flashpunk.Entity;
import net.flashpunk.graphics.Image;
import net.flashpunk.FP;
import net.flashpunk.utils.Draw;

public class PlayerBrokenHUD extends Entity 
{

    [Embed(source = "graphics/SpaceShipHudbroken.png")] private const BHUD : Class;

    public function PlayerBrokenHUD() 
    {

        graphic = new Image(BHUD);
        graphic.scrollX = graphic.scrollY = 0;
        y = FP.screen.height - 70;

        Draw.circle(100, 100, 100, 0xD5BB5C);

    }
}
}
```

All of the code works fine, the circle shows up, as does the graphic. However the circle disappears after the first frame. I have tried the Draw class in other scripts and projects but keep getting the same result. I tried doing it in an update function but still get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override render method of your entity. The Draw.circle() will be called for each frame. Do remember that it will be drawn according to layer value. So if it HUD it's layer should be very small or negative even.

```
override public function render():void 
{
    Draw.circle(100, 100, 100, 0xD5BB5C); // draw circle
    super.render(); // paste sprite from graphics
}
```